# How to solve the NaN value in SVM classifier?

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I use libsvm toolbox to classify multiple class dataset. In my case,
I have 9 classes. The following is my code:

```
model = ovrtrainBot(trainLabel, trainData, type);

[predict_label, accuracy, decis_values] = ovrpredictBot(testLabel, testData, model);
```

I set kernel type to `"1"`, which is polynomial, since I found
this will give the best classification accuracy. But the problem is 
the parameter `accuracy` gives all `NaN` values in its 3rd row. The 
parameter `"accuracy"` shown as follows:

```
63.63%  92.56% 92.56%  92.56%  92.56%  92.56%   92.56%   92.56%   92.56%
0.3636  0.0744  0.0744 0.0744  0.0744  0.0744   0.0744   0.0744   0.0744
NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN
```

If I use kernel `t = 0(linear)`, the 3rd row of accuracy will all have values, but the classification accuracy is much lower than I use `kernel t=1`.

Can anyone give me a help to fix the problem?

Comment: @Hoki,  can you answer this question? Really appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry but I have absolutely no knowledge of the subject. What is the third row supposed to mean ? ... may be it's normal to have them as `NaN` in some case ... or at least not worrying, if the final accuracy is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the squared correlation coefficient (http://www.openpr.org.cn/files/help/rn01re18.html) which isn't relevant for a classification problem

Comment: Do you mean even if it is NaN , it is still OK? Do not matter?

Comment: Yes, you should safely be able to ignore it